# When the OP votes to close own question as a duplicate, immediately close the question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When a user votes to close their own question as a duplicate, it is treated like any regular vote to close, auto-adding a comment to the page suggesting the possible duplicate.

[image: Possible Duplicate comment]

Upon refreshing the page, the user is prompted to re-confirm that yes, their question is a duplicate.

[image: "This question may already have an answer here:" - You don't say?]
 <sub>"*This question may already have an answer here*" - **You don't say? :P**</sub>

Users can already decide to close their own question as a duplicate. It only takes a single extra step to confirm the closure.

When a user votes to close their own question as a duplicate, shouldn't the question be closed instantly without needing to refresh and reconfirm?

Comment: OPs cannot unilaterally close their own questions. The status-completed there is only a reference that they can now click the button shown there to let *Community* close it.

Comment: @animuson Updated to remove that claim

Comment: **If so**, I can post a new question and vote to close it as a dupe of [the sandbox](/q/3122). Does that make sense?

Comment: @iBug You already ***can*** do that. Post a question, flag as duplicate, confirm "Yes this answered my question".

Comment: @animuson if the OP has a gold badge in the tags on their question - does that affect anything? (or because they were the ones to add them - the dupehammer won't work anyway...)

Comment: @JonClements Will still use gold tag badge power. Simply the fact that they are the owner of the question does not have any bearing on the outcome. Everything else still works normally.

Comment: I think that the OP's vote to close their own question should be binding if they have the privilege to vote to close their own questions, no matter if it's as a duplicate or something else. I don't see how a user could abuse the system by closing their own question.

Comment: Better try the delete button.